# windows 2008 R2 server domain with www not working(multiple sites) IIS 7

Tags: windows, iis-7, webserver, web-hosting

I have web server with multiple websites, I can't access site by typing wwww.mysite.com
,I get it by typing only mysite.com.
lets look at this site http://myvnm.com/ ,
I set the bindings,and URL Rewrite ...

Comment: Ohh.... Check your binding correctly and add CNAME on your CP.

Comment: how to add CNAME ,i can't connect to the DNS Manager->connect server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't setup you host header correctly. You'll need to point things coming in on "www" to the correct location as well.

Try this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx

Hope this helps.